Webcam not working after 24.04 - not fixed by pipewire restart
I updated from 22.04 to 24.04 and my webcam has stopped working on my Dell Precision 5680, which was working fine before the update. I've updated all the things, rebooted, etc.  The common advice for this seems to be restarting pipewire and running snapshot, but that doesn't work.  The camera is found, but gives a stream error.  Here's the terminal output:
:~$ systemctl --user restart pipewire
:~$ snapshot 
2024-09-05T18:39:40.888204Z  INFO snapshot::application::imp: Snapshot (org.gnome.Snapshot)    
2024-09-05T18:39:40.888222Z  INFO snapshot::application::imp: Version: 46.2    
2024-09-05T18:39:40.888227Z  INFO snapshot::application::imp: Datadir: /usr/share/snapshot    
2024-09-05T18:39:41.417120Z ERROR aperture::viewfinder: Could not start camerabin: Element failed to change its state    
2024-09-05T18:39:41.419195Z ERROR aperture::viewfinder: Could not start camerabin: Element failed to change its state    
2024-09-05T18:39:41.419653Z ERROR aperture::viewfinder: Bus Error from Some("/GstCameraBin:camerabin0/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camerasrc/GstAutoVideoSrc:camerasrc-real-src/GstPipeWireSrc:camerasrc-real-src-actual-src-pipewir")
stream error: can't negotiate buffers on port
Some("../src/gst/gstpipewiresrc.c(692): on_state_changed (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin0/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camerasrc/GstAutoVideoSrc:camerasrc-real-src/GstPipeWireSrc:camerasrc-real-src-actual-src-pipewir")    
2024-09-05T18:39:41.419690Z ERROR aperture::viewfinder: Bus Error from Some("/GstCameraBin:camerabin0/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camerasrc/GstAutoVideoSrc:camerasrc-real-src/GstPipeWireSrc:camerasrc-real-src-actual-src-pipewir")
Internal data stream error.
Some("../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3177): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin0/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camerasrc/GstAutoVideoSrc:camerasrc-real-src/GstPipeWireSrc:camerasrc-real-src-actual-src-pipewir:\nstreaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)")    
2024-09-05T18:39:52.794885Z ERROR snapshot::widgets::window::imp: Could not take picture: The viewfinder is not in the READY state    
e


An external Logitech USB webcam does work, so I think this is some sort of driver issue?
